# How to show more than one button based on prompts from QnAMaker in bot

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, bots, chatbot

I'm trying to make a chatbot for MS Teams, a simple question-and-answer bot, and my actual difficulty is to show buttons on it depending on prompts from DB, I can show one, but in QnAMaker has more than one.

As you know, MS Teams doesn't works with suggested actions, so I'm trying with herocards.
Below is a code that I'm making.
Hope you guys can help me.

Below has images that can show you

[code that I'm trying to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F25bC.png)

[Bot emulator showing just one button but two options in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djfcu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did it! The issue were just on simple changes on the code,
Here is the code that show normally the buttons with context;

// When a user sends a message, perform a call to the QnA Maker service to retrieve matching Question and Answer pairs.

```
    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        this.logger.log('Calling QnA Maker');
        const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);
        const reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };

        const buttons = qnaResults[0].context.prompts.map(value => ({
            type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
            title: value.displayText,
            value: value.displayText
        }));
        const card = CardFactory.heroCard(qnaResults[0].Question, undefined, buttons, { text: qnaResults[0].answer });
        reply.attachments = [card];
```